# rewrite url in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

My codeigniter website current url is www.websitename.com/fronend/deals/index/all/all.
(note:frontend is folder inside controller, and deals is controller)

I wants to change it to www.websitename.com/deals/ using htaccess. I had tried some code but not able to do that.Is that possible to change it using htaccess.

Previously, I had removed the index.php from the url of my codeigniter site using following htaccess code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

this is working fine.So I think, I needs to add some rewrite rule for this.

could u pls explain me how to do this.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need htaccess

in

```
.\application\config\routs.php
```

add

```
$route['deals'] = "fronend/deals/index/all/all";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had added this code in routs.php file but when I am opening the www.websitename.com/deals, it is showing 404 error. any suggestion for that.

Comment: Did you check for spelling errors? (I see fronend spelled there)

Comment: yes, u are right, great observation. Thanks for help max and Coccodrillo.Thanks a lot :)